# change cxf ws-addressing properties in camel route

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

i am using cxf as a producer in an apache camel route with WS-Addressing.
I know that it is possible to set the SoapAction Header inside the route via (just as example might be wrong)

```
...
.setHeader("SoapAction").constant("anysoapactionwanted")
.to("cxf...
```

is it possible to the same with the WS-Addressing Action field? Because i noticed it is sent with the wrong value. There are 2 WS-Addressing Action values i need to put in and it is decided in the camel route which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

You must be deciding the the required operation based on some value. In that case use Choice-When conditional block to derive correct action.